# FreeRTOS scheduler performing context switching for the same task

Tags: operating-system, real-time, freertos, context-switch

I noticed strange behavior when debugging the system I am analyzing. The system has three periodic tasks:

"Task-1", with 10 milliseconds of periodicity. High priority.

"Task-2", with 10 milliseconds of periodicity. Medium priority.

"Task-3" with 10 milliseconds of periodicity. Low priority.

The content of the three tasks is just a critical section, a critical section that is shared. The inversion of priorities occurs frequently, and I am forcing this situation to see how the system behaves temporally. The Systick has a period of 1ms.

From what I read about FreeRTOS, in Cortex-M the context change of a task is done through a pending bit, which in the scenario of periodic tasks can be activated through:

1. Tick timer handler finds a task with the highest priority in the
   ready queue and sets the pending context switch bit;
2. In the “vDelayTaskUntil” function, which waits for the next
   activation;
3. When a semaphore is busy and the task that tries to acquire it.

That said, I found this behavior:

Sometimes, while the high priority task is within the semaphore, the context switching takes place for itself, as explained below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7aa9.png]

As noted, task-1 does a context switch for itself.

Do you know how to tell me why this happens?

Attaching the code of test:

Task-1:

```
void vTask1_handler(void *params) {
    TickType_t xLastWakeTime;
    const TickType_t xFrequency = 10;
    xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();
    int i = 0, to =0;

for (;;) {
    vTaskDelayUntil(&xLastWakeTime, xFrequency);
    to = DWT->CYCCNT;
    for (i = 0; i < to % 500; i++);
    if (xSemaphoreTake(xSemaphore, portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE) {
        to = DWT->CYCCNT;
        for (i = 0; i < to % 5000; i++);
        xSemaphoreGive(xSemaphore);
    }

}
}
```

Task-2:

```
void vTask2_handler(void *params) {
    TickType_t xLastWakeTime;
    const TickType_t xFrequency = 10;
    xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();
    int i = 0, to = 0;

for (;;) {
    vTaskDelayUntil(&xLastWakeTime, xFrequency);
    to = DWT->CYCCNT;
    for (i = 0; i < to % 200; i++);
    if (xSemaphoreTake(xSemaphore, portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE) {
        to = DWT->CYCCNT;
        for (i = 0; i < to % 10000; i++);
        xSemaphoreGive(xSemaphore);
    }
}
```

Task-3:

```
void vTask3_handler(void *params) {
    TickType_t xLastWakeTime;
    const TickType_t xFrequency = 10;
    xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();
    int i = 0, to=0;

for (;;) {
    vTaskDelayUntil(&xLastWakeTime, xFrequency);
    to = DWT->CYCCNT;
    for (i = 0; i < to % 200; i++);
    if (xSemaphoreTake(xSemaphore, portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE) {
        to = DWT->CYCCNT;
        for (i = 0; i < to % 10000; i++);
        xSemaphoreGive(xSemaphore);
    }
}
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is going to the scheduler in the give or take semaphore API call and concluding it is still the highest priority ready task.

Answer (score 0):

freertos have a periodic interrupt, that when happening it is checking if it is now time to unblock or wake a task. I think what you see is this interrupt.

please look at https://www.freertos.org/implementation/a00011.html for details about the tick interrupt.

you also may want to look at https://www.freertos.org/low-power-tickless-rtos.html if you want to disable it when entering idle low power task.